# Error on updating a tranaction netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitetalk

I am trying to update a transaction using suite talk API and getting below error,for all the records with closed posting period. for rest of all transaction(with open posting period) API working fine.

**This bill has payments applied to it.  Are you sure you want to edit it? Code -: WARNING**

Thanks in advance,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting same warning when edit and save in Netsuite environment ? Three places you can check the configurations :
1- Period Record
2- Period related configuration in Accounting Prferences under Setup tab
3- Web Services cinfiguration in Netsuite

Comment: Thanks Shoaib,                                                                                                                     This was not working because it was disabled on Net-suite also.Now i am trying to update journal entries on Net-suite using suite talk API but it is giving error for max line item 1000,Is there any way to update journal entry detail have more than 1000 child records.